# Pass A Value From Outside To A Plugin Variable

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters, hooks

Is there a way to pass a custom variable value from outside like from functions.php to a plugin's variable?

Lets say that I have the following function defined in a plugin.

```
function plugin_funct(){

 $var1 = 0;
 if(var1 == 0)
 {
    return false;

 }
 else
 {
      echo "Variable passed";

 }

}
```

Now, is there a way to pass some value to "var1" from functions.php etc? By adding any filter or action? Something like

```
function passValue()
{
    $var1 = 1;

}
add_filter("plugin_funct", "passValue");
```

So that we get the "else" condition in the plugin's function "plugin_funct". Possible?

Comment: Why do you need it with such an early timing? There shouldn't be much logic running during `functions.php` load.

Answer (score 0):

You can with filter.

On your plugin :

```
 $value = 0;
 $value = apply_filter('get_value_from_function', $value);
```

Then on functions.php

```
add_filter('get_value_from_function', 'my_special_value_treatment', 10, 1);
function my_special_value_treatment ($value){
    return 1;
}
```