# Pass info from functions.php to plugin

Tags: plugins, functions, filters, hooks

What is the best way to pass some information from `functions.php` to a plugin?

I need to give a user the ability to *pass* a piece of data *from* their `functions.php` file *to* my plugin. (It can be any data, just something that I can check for; it can be a variable's value, or even the fact that a variable was set or a function was defined.)

I tried the suggestion found here:

[Pass A Value From Outside To A Plugin Variable](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169284/pass-a-value-from-outside-to-a-plugin-variable)

I plugged in that code verbatim:

*On your plugin :*

```
 $value = 0;
 $value = apply_filter('get_value_from_function', $value);
```

*Then on `functions.php`*

```
add_filter('get_value_from_function', 'my_special_value_treatment', 10, 1);
function my_special_value_treatment ($value){
    return 1;
}
```

But that results in an error:

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined function apply_filter() in /pathtomyplugin/my-plugin-name/my-plugin-name.php on line 93

I don't understand why that fails. What is the best way to do this?

*Edited with this addition:*

After changing it to `apply_filters()`, this still happens... In my plugin:

```
$value = 0;
$value = apply_filters('get_value_from_function', $value);
if ($value===0) {
    $test_info = 'not_passed';
} else {
    $test_info = 'passed';
};
// $test_info is not_passed
```

Comment: Is your `$value = apply_filters('get_value_from_function', $value);` wrapped in a function? How is that function called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins are loaded before the theme which means that your `apply_filters` won't have any actual callbacks registered to it. Instead, you need to call your `apply_filters` sometime after the theme has been loaded. Something like this:

```
/* Your plugin's file: */

add_action( 'init', 'my_lovely_funky_filters' );

function my_lovely_funky_filters() {
    /* Fire our callbacks */
    $value = 0;
    $value = apply_filters( 'get_value_from_function', $value );

    /* Check your $value now */
    /* echo "<pre>{$value}</pre>"; */
}

/* Your functions.php file */

add_filter( 'get_value_from_function', 'my_special_value_treatment', 10, 1 );
function my_special_value_treatment( $value ) {
    /* A little more interesting */
    return (int)$value + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question I asked. Still can't get some other related things to work, but that will have to be a second question!

Comment: So now the value of `$value` is indeterminate until the init action fires; I can't seem to access its final value from within the plugin file. How can I retrieve it and use it in my plugin file?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct method - except the function is `apply_filters`, not apply_filter. Hence your error.

Comment: Still no good. I added more details above.